# exiting batch file within a subroutine

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a Script with different subroutines:

```
REM ---------------MAIN------------------------START----------------------------
call :SUB_GetStartTime
call :SUB_SettingVariables 
call :SUB_CheckingParameters %* 
call :SUB_Copy 
call :SUB_GetEndTime
call :SUB_WriteLog
call :SUB_EndScreen

REM ---------------MAIN------------------------END------------------------------
```

At SUB_CheckingParameters I have this if query:

```
if "%~1"=="/help" (
    GOTO SUB_HELP
)
```

If I pass the parameter /help it goes to my help window:

```
cls
ECHO ===================HELP==============
ECHO help text help text help text
ECHO =====================================
timeout /t 120
exit /b
```

after `exit /b` I want the script to end but it just goes to my next subroutine (SUB_Copy). Shouldnt the script end because I use `GOTO SUB_Help` and not `call` ?

Can someone help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The `EXIT /B` acts the same as `GOTO :EOF`. See also `CALL a subroutine (:label)` at https://ss64.com/nt/call.html

Comment: Just do `exit` without /b or `goto :EOF`

Comment: `goto :EOF` does the same as `exit /b` and `exit` closes cmd, I dont want that.

Comment: Then where do you want to go to?

Comment: Create a label for `:main` and then simply do `goto :main` instead of `exit /b`

Answer (score 1):

I ususally handle this by passing back an errorlevel:

```
@Echo off
REM ---------------MAIN------------------------START----------------------------
call :SUB_GetStartTime
call :SUB_SettingVariables 
call :SUB_CheckingParameters %* || Exit /b 1
call :SUB_Copy 
call :SUB_GetEndTime
call :SUB_WriteLog
call :SUB_EndScreen
REM ---------------MAIN------------------------END------------------------------
Echo end of main
Pause
Goto :Eof

:SUB_CheckingParameters
if /I "%~1"=="/help" GOTO SUB_HELP

:SUB_GetStartTime
:SUB_SettingVariables
:SUB_Copy
:SUB_GetEndTime
:SUB_WriteLog
:SUB_EndScreen

Echo:We are in %~0 Args %*
Goto :Eof

:SUB_HELP
rem cls
ECHO ===================HELP==============
ECHO help text help text help text
ECHO =====================================
timeout /t 120
exit /b 1
```